# Videos downloaded from Google Photos won't play with QuickTime Player

Tags: video, quicktime, imovie, google-photos

I get this error when I try to play videos downloaded from *Google Photos* on the QuickTime player:

> This file contains some media which isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player. Would you like to open the file anyway?

If I press "continue" the QuickTime player plays just the audio from the video as if it were an audio file.

Before uploading to *Google Photos*, these videos were taken via iPhone or screen recordings made using QuickTime and have either .mov or .mp4 extensions when they are uploaded. The downloaded files have the same extension. Nevertheless, I suspect some processing occurs that causes the problem.

The problem happens whether the videos are edited (using QT, iMovie, ffmpeg) or not. I did some tests and the problem does not occur if I download immediately after uploading -- but if I download from *Google Photos* just 10 hours later or so, the problem occurs.

I am able to fix this problem using ffmpeg (see below), but that requires a lot of time and didn't used to have to do that. I believe this problem started within the past few months or so.

I am using QuickTime 10.5 on Mac OS 14.0 on a 2020 MacAir (M1). I'm also using iMovie 10.4 and ffmpeg 6.1.1

Anything else I can do?

##### More details

Regarding the editing that I do, it is done using QT or iMovie, exporting the result with higher quality (which produces .mp4) and then adjusting video size and quality with ffmpeg commands such as:

```
ffmpeg -i large.mp4 -s 640:360 -c:a copy small.mp4
```

or even just:

```
ffmpeg -i large.mp4 small.mp4
```

Then I upload to *Google Photos*, wait 10+ hours and the problem occurs. The ffmpeg command I use to fix the problem is:

```
ffmpeg -i GooglePhotoDownload.mp4 converted.mp4
```

The "converted.mp4" will then play video with QuickTime.

Comment: Two questions. (1) What is the file extension of the downloaded file? (2) Where in the process does Google Photos  come into play?

Comment: @SteveM thanks for your question. I modified the original post to answer your questions and also fixed some errors I'd made when writing it

Comment: I have been noticing the same recently.